# Prometheus endpoint error when using micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to setup Prometheus monitoring on Spring boot application But getting an error: `Get https://example.com:8080/actuator/prometheus: EOF`

**My Setup**

`application.yml`

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

`Prometheus config`

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     5s # Set the scrape interval to every 5 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 5s # Evaluate rules every 5 seconds.

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'app'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scheme: https
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ['example.com:8080']
```

Now, When browsing to `actuator/prometheus`, I can see data:

```
# HELP hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds Connection usage time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds summary ....
....
```

But On Prometheous targets screen, I can see the correct Url but with the specified error.

I'm running Prometheus Using Docker.

```
level=info ts=2018-08-14T19:10:59.6844594Z caller=main.go:603 msg="Loading   configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2018-08-14T19:10:59.686749Z caller=main.go:629 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2018-08-14T19:10:59.6867898Z caller=main.go:502 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
```

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus targets screen displaying EOF error indicates that there is something wrong in prometheus.yml file

Change the scrape configs in your prometheus config file

`- job_name: 'person-app'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['example.com:8080']`

targets should include your hostname, not the url.
Restart your prometheus after changing the config file

*For updated yml file*

The scheme tag should be above static_configs. The correct declaration should be

`job_name: 'person-app'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scheme: 'https'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['example.com:8080']`

Comment: Sorry, gave a wrong yml example. Updated to the "real" yml config file (Using scheme)

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the new yml config file

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sania. I'm getting the same error (both with scheme: https and scheme: 'https'

Comment: Nothing interesting really, Added

Answer (score 0):

I created [a sample to reproduce your issue](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/so-51765772) but failed. Note that the sample is on the `so-51765772`, not `master` and [I changed `scheme` and `target` from your Prometheus configuration](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/so-51765772/setup/prometheus/prometheus.yml#L8-L10) to reproduce easily as follows:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     5s # Set the scrape interval to every 5 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 5s # Evaluate rules every 5 seconds.

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'app'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scheme: http
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

I guess the problem might be somewhere else. So if you can make this sample fail the way you're seeing, I can take another look.